# IIS rewrite rule to black-hole URL's with an apostrophe

Tags: security, iis, rewrite, windows-server-2019

I bought a web app that does not use special characters. In reviewing my logs, I am seeing probing by threat actors who attempt to see if my site is vulnerable to SQL injection by adding apostrophes and other char() characters that are never normally used. I trust the security of my app (mostly), but wanted to see if a rewrite rule or some other methodology would black-hole their request. My web app gives out its standard error. I am looking for rules or ideas to 1.) give the attacker as little info as possible without 2.) adding a lot of overhead to the server. There are lots of rewrite rule examples out there, but none that I have found that deal with this angle.

Simple Example of the probing: `https://sub.domain.com/default.aspx?page=3500'A=0&Id=497066`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? It will weed out some of the nastier SQL characters.

```
  <system.webServer>
      <rules>
        <rule name="No SQL injection" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="['\(\);]" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
  </system.webServer>
```

This will abort the request if any of the characters `'();` appear in the query string.

[No SQL Injection rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FotP.png)
[image]

Comment: Where does this XML go? Can you also provide a screenshot of the GUI version of the rule?

Comment: @wruckie It goes in the web.config file, which is on the root folder of your website. The system.webServer node should already be in the file. I'll see if I can add some screenshots to my answer.

Comment: @wruckie Added the screenshot. I don't have enough "reputation" to embed the screenshot so just click the link at the bottom of the answer.